# Typescript: Make class in function known to ts

Tags: angularjs, typescript

So I have my classes defined in angular factory functions:

```
export default function ($resource, $http:angular.IHttpService) {
  return class Account{}
}
```

I also have a all.ts where my typings of definitelytyped are included. When I want to use Account in another class, I inject it with:

```
class AccountsController {
  public static $inject = ['Account'];
  constructor(public Account:Account){}
}
```

However, Account is unknown and even if I add the factory file to all.ts references, it does not find it.

How can I make Account known to typescript, ideally without defining the interface again (as it is already defined through the class, isn't it?).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
export function theService(...): theService {
  return {
    theServiceMethod1: function(id) {
  }
}

export declare interface theService {
  theServiceMethod1(id): void;
  ....
}
```

The same can be applied to a class as well. The class members are known, but the return type of the exported functions are not as far as I can tell.